# como definir espaço entre os botões no Android?

Tags: android, xml

Estou utilizando 3 botões num `Linear Layout`.
Gostaria de distribuir os espaços entre os botões.

Segue a imagem como exexmplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

xml da tela:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="texto1"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:onClick="botao1"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="texto2"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:onClick="botao2"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="texto3"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:onClick="botao3"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além dos botões terá de usar uma *view* "vazia"<sup>(1)</sup> para representar os espaços antes, entre e depois de cada botão.

É utilizado atributo [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) para dimensionar os espaços de forma igual.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="texto1"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:onClick="botao1"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="texto2"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:onClick="botao2"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="texto3"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:onClick="botao3"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

<sup>(1)</sup> Se *minSdkVersion* for igual a 14 ou superior pode substituir

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

por:

```
<Space
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: você pode dar uma dica, adicionei mais uma fileira de botões tem como dar um pequeno espaço entre o botão de cima com o de baixo.

Comment: Se você duplicar o xml que eu postei para representar a nova fileira ela ficará `15dp` abaixo da primeira. Inclua as duas em um *LinearLayout*.

Comment: eu fiz  isso um botão de cima ficou colado no outro de baixo

Comment: O LinearLayout tem `android:layout_marginTop="15dp"` logo deveriam ficar separados por `15dp`

Comment: estava faltando este código, deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar espaçamento entres os botões você pode usar o **layout_margin**:

```
android:layout_margin="10dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

Contudo, há várias formas para que eles sejam igualmente espaçados e aliados com a tela do usuário.

**Um forma:**
Centralize os elementos do Linearlayout e coloque margens no segundo botão

```
<LinearLayout
        ...
        android:gravity="center">
        ...
        <Button
            ...
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
```

[image: LinearLayout com elementos centralizados e espaçados]

Veja que a distância entre os botões são as mesma - 15dp - mas não é a mesma distância entre os lados do celular.

**Outra forma:** 
Use o **[layout_weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)** para definir a quantos % o elemento irá ocupar do elemento pai.(Nesse caso 1/3 = 0.33333...) 
Note que usei uma LinearLayout como intermediário para que o botão não ficasse esticado e sim o LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".333333333">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="texto1"
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:onClick="botao1"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".333333333">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="texto2"
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:onClick="botao2"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".333333333">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="texto3"
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:onClick="botao3"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]